# Problem with Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

Tags: asp.net, events, membership-provider

I put the following algorithm into the login control event. It is fired after the user has logged in. A nuller point exception is thrown.

Answer is updated!! A new exception is thrown, it tells me that cast is not valid

```
   MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName,true);
        int i = (int)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

I am assuming that this event is only fired if the user successfully logged in, and not failed.. should i use another event or objects. please help!!!

Comment: what happens if you use the parameterless `Membership.GetUser();`? Do you still get a null reference? Do you have a MembershipProvider configured?

Comment: yeah, i do. It took me days to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName, true);
```

then use

```
user.ProviderUserKey
```

Comment: MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName,true);
        int i = (int)CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey;  Specified cast is not valid

Comment: what is the value of CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey?

Comment: it says the cast is wrong..i try to get an int. i thought userkey is an int

Comment: it looks as a string, {323123231-321321-343243-3asfdsa}.. definitely not an int.. so should i use it as a string. ?

Comment: public virtual Object ProviderUserKey { get; }

Comment: string userKey=urrentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

Comment: it wont let me even to cast it to a string. it says it is a GUID. no idea how i can convert it

Comment: Guid userKey =(Guid)urrentUser.ProviderUserKey;

Comment: But if i put it into a table... what property can i choose? nvarchar?

Comment: Is there anything wron with it? does it have cons and pros? or is it same as using a unique int

Comment: Here's an article about it http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html or try google with "guid vs int"

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the current user from the current HTTP Context. I believe the static instance you've passed to the GetUser method will not be populated with the users credentials.

Give this a try:

```
MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(this.Context.User.Identity.Name);
```

Assuming your membership setup is working you should be able to retrieve the current user and if not, you need to handle the case that the user is not found- e.g by asking the user to login.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have typed should work, but you can also use Parameter-less one

```
Membership.GetUser();
```

this helps you when user is logged in. but when no user is logged in `User.Identity.Name` is not correct. you can check with `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

in login page use this :

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Login1.UserName, true);
```

Comment: so i should use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, in an if statement to check if he is logged in..otherwise exceptions might be thrown?